# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED after upgrade the project from vc6 to vc9

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

The function which were written in vc6.

```
bool CProductionTestDlg::GetVariables(CString strFilename, CMapStringToOb *cVariableMap)
{
    int     iMaxEntryLen   = 1000;
    //char    rgbEntryNames[1000];                //previous
    char  *rgbEntryNames = (char*)malloc(iMaxEntryLen * sizeof(int)); //Now
    CString strEntryName   = "";
    CString strEntryValue  = "";
    UINT    uiSeperator    = 0;
    ULONG   dwRetCode, dwSizeOfReturn;

    dwSizeOfReturn = GetPrivateProfileString(cszVariables,
                                            NULL,
                                            "",
                                            rgbEntryNames,
                                            iMaxEntryLen,
                                            strFilename);

    while ( uiSeperator < dwSizeOfReturn )
    {
        strEntryName.Format("%s", &rgbEntryNames[uiSeperator]);
        uiSeperator += strEntryName.GetLength() + 1;

        CString *strValue = new CString();
        dwRetCode = GetPrivateProfileString(cszVariables,
                                            strEntryName,
                                            "",
                                            strEntryValue.GetBufferSetLength(strEntryValue.GetLength()),
                                            iMaxEntryLen,
                                            strFilename);
        strValue->Format("%s", strEntryValue);        
        cVariableMap->SetAt(strEntryName, (CObject*)strValue);

    }

    return true;
}
```

Now I upgrade it on vs08.The project build correctly but when I open exe it throw an exception

**HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED ** CRT Detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

When I debug the my application the the control goes to **dbgheap.c** at line no 2103 after return true.

Comment: I think the buffer rgbEntryNames is too small

Comment: I tried but the problem is remain same......

Comment: @Jeeva look at the question I have edit it.......

Comment: @vikky Use the call stack window to go to the context of CProductionTestDlg::GetVariables. That way you will see which line in the function caused the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
dwRetCode = GetPrivateProfileString(cszVariables, 
    strEntryName, 
    "", 
    strEntryValue.GetBufferSetLength(strEntryValue.GetLength()), 
    iMaxEntryLen, 
    strFilename);
```

You pass a buffer of size 0 (`strEntryValue` is initialized to `""`), but say its size is `iMaxEntryLen`. So `GetPrivateProfileString` thinks it has a much larger buffer than it actually got, and write beyond its bounds.

The reason you get this error after upgrading is, is guess, the improvement of the bounds validation. The bug was there in VC6 as well, it just wasn't detected.